# dplyr: subset rows based on count of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to subset rows of a dataframe based on the number of observations in a given column such that I only get rows where there are *n*+ observations. I want to do this using Tidyverse functions, not base R functions.

For example: from the `planes` data from the `nycflights13` package, keep all the rows where `planes$manufacturer` has at least 10 observations. The subset data should only have the following manufacturers:

```
[1] "AIRBUS"                        "AIRBUS INDUSTRIE"              "BOEING"                       
[4] "BOMBARDIER INC"                "EMBRAER"                       "MCDONNELL DOUGLAS"            
[7] "MCDONNELL DOUGLAS AIRCRAFT CO" "MCDONNELL DOUGLAS CORPORATION"
```

Note: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284695/subset-rows-based-on-values-of-a-column) does not address this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- planes %>%
  dplyr::group_by(manufacturer) %>%
  dplyr::filter(n() > 10)
```

Summary of Output

```
df %>% count(manufacturer)

# A tibble: 8 × 2
# Groups:   manufacturer [8]
  manufacturer                      n
  <chr>                         <int>
1 AIRBUS                          336
2 AIRBUS INDUSTRIE                400
3 BOEING                         1630
4 BOMBARDIER INC                  368
5 EMBRAER                         299
6 MCDONNELL DOUGLAS               120
7 MCDONNELL DOUGLAS AIRCRAFT CO   103
8 MCDONNELL DOUGLAS CORPORATION    14
```